# How can I add a virtual "count" column to a select query in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a post model, and post has_many :comments, :as => :commentable (polymorphic).  I am looking for a way that I can fetch all posts, and have a virtual attribute on the record which will display how many comments belong to that post.

I was thinking that I could just do:

```
Post.select("posts.*, count(comments.id) as post_comments").joins(:comments)
```

However, that returns only one record, with post_comments set to ALL comments in the entire database, not just those belonging to the record...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `count(comments.id)` just does one count for the entire joined table. You can get around this with a nested query:

```rb
Post.select("posts.*, (SELECT count(comments.id) FROM comments WHERE comments.post_id=posts.id) AS post_comments")
```

You don't need the join in this case, since the comments table is not used in the outer query.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, what you are missing is a group clause.  You need to group by site, otherwise the count() aggregation collapses everything to one record as you see.

Try this:

```
Post.select("posts.*, count(comments.id) as post_comments")
    .joins(:comments)
    .group('posts.id')
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do that with variables in Post model. 1st I would try to find the post I am looking for somehow (you can find it by wichever parameter you want,below I show the example with searching the id param).

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
```

When you find the post you were looking for, finding out comment number is preety easy, try something along the lines of...

```
@comments = @post.comments.size
```

...wich would return an integer.